# Views at the cost of caching - worth it?

Tags: channel-entries

I want to keep track of the number of times my single entry page is viewed. However, it seems that I have to disable page caching in order to do this. How much of a performance penalty will that be? Are there alternatives to counting the number of page views? I want to be able to display the page views, sort by page views, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an average site I would say that although there will be a performance impact it is highly unlikely to create any issues, or even be noticed.

When you scale up to bigger sites these things can be an issue but I think you need to be pulling a lot of traffic for that to become serious.

Of course, this is just my opinion and completely anecdotal. Faster is better but I do firmly believe that many folk worry about this unnecessarily. Often quite fast is fast enough.

Comment: This is my gut feeling, too. However, I don't even have anecdotal evidence to back me up. Perhaps I should just give it a try and then revisit the issue if it becomes a problem? I tend not to like that approach, though. If I know it's going to be an issue, I'd rather try to avoid it.

Comment: I agree with this.

Comment: Yeah, I would just try it and monitor how it goes. You'll probably find that even if, by developer standards, it is slow an inefficient your users won't be too troubled by waiting an extra 10ms.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ExpressionEngine to track page view? The way I generally desable all tracking in EE and rely on external services to provide me with the analytics I need. That way, I can be totally independent from caching.

To me EE is not the right tool for that. Any dedicated analytics service will be better at it.

Google Analytics is such a service at an entry level. While sufficient for most users, you might want to supplement it with other systems on bigger projects.

Comment: I just want to show how many times a blog post, for example, has been viewed. Wouldn't it be more expensive to get that information from Google Analytics if I had to display 20 blog post on a single page with each one needing to show the page views?

Comment: You are displaying page views on the front end?